# How to track re-entries of a contact into a Marketing Cloud journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I can't quite solve this one. I'm building a few gated content journeys in Marketing Cloud's Journey Builder to deliver free downloads, followed by a couple more emails. I want to allow re-entry (after exiting) for people who want the content again (lost it or forgot about requesting it, etc.). But I want to track re-entries. My usual process is a DateCompleted column in the associated data extension that gets updated just before exiting the journey, but I don't want to overwrite this value when a person re-enters the journey.

I can think of two desirable alternative outcomes:

1. Add the DateCompleted date, and append a new date for each re-entry.
2. Iterate a count of entries in a Completed column with each entry, telling me how many times a single contact has completed the journey.

As I've explored the Journey Builder actions, I can't come up with a way to accomplish either alternative. ***Is this even possible?*** Surely I'm not the only person to want this out of Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way may work for you.

I would create a date field in the Journey entry DE where I can put a default value for the time that contact enters/re-enters the journey.

From email studio >> data extension >> go to the journey DE

1. Create a date field to capture the time a contact enters the journey. Let's call "DateEnter"
2. Copy and paste **GETDATE()** into the default value for the date field.

[image]

Now every time a contact is injected into the journey, it will capture the date they enter.

Note: the date time is followed by the Marketing Cloud system time UTC-6 with no daylight savings.